# Write a sum like a sum with Σ

Tags: summation

So, we have the following sum: $S = 1/2 - 4/3 + 9/4 - 16/5 + 25/6$

and we have to write it as a $\sum_{k = 1}^5ak$ and $\sum_{k = 2}^6bk$

I'm not sure if I have to make $S = \sum ak - \sum bk$ or if there is a way to make S equal to only one sum, in two ways. But anyway I cant figure it using either approach.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use MathJax to write your question.

Answer (score 6):

$$S=\sum_{j=1}^{j=5}\frac {(-1)^{j+1}.j^2}{j+1}$$